# Changing JPanel Graphics g color drawing line

Tags: java, swing, drawing, mouselistener

i have a program similar to paint. and that i am trying to implement a change pen color however when i change the color, everything currently drawn is changed to the color RED for example in my program,how can i make it such that it will not repaint everything currently drawn to the currently changed color?Below code will compile and run

Class for the JPanel drawing area

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
//refer to http://jkost.ergoway.gr/jnkjavaconnection/freedraw.html for the algorithm.
public class STDrawingArea extends JPanel {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    ArrayList<Rectangle> dPoint = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
    Point point = new Point(-1,-1);
    private Color currentColor;

    public STDrawingArea()
    {
         setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
         setBackground(Color.WHITE);

         addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) 
            {
                dPoint.add(new Rectangle(point.x,point.y,e.getX(),e.getY()));
                point.x = e.getX();
                point.y = e.getY();
                repaint();
            }

             });

         addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
             public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
             {
                 System.out.println("mousePressed X: "+e.getX()+"mousePressed Y: "+e.getY());
                 dPoint.add(new Rectangle(e.getX(),e.getY(),-1,-1));
                 point.x = e.getX();
                 point.y = e.getY();
             }
         });

         addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
             public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
             {
                 System.out.println("mouseReleased X: "+e.getX()+"mouseReleased Y: "+e.getY());
                 repaint();
             }
         });
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(700,500);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
       g.setColor(getCurrentColor());
        for (int i=0; i < dPoint.size(); i++) {  
            Rectangle r = dPoint.get(i);
            if (r.width != -1)
            {
              g.drawLine(r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height);  
            }
           }  
            /* Draw current point.*/ 
            g.drawLine(point.x, point.y, point.x, point.y);  
    }

    //set current drawing color
    public void changePenColor(Color color)
    {
        if (color == null)
        setCurrentColor(Color.BLACK);
        else
        setCurrentColor(color);
    }

    //clear drawings method
    public void clearDrawings()
    {
        if(!(dPoint==null))
        {
             dPoint.clear();
             repaint();
        }

    }

    private void setCurrentColor(Color currentColor) {
        this.currentColor = currentColor;
    }

    private Color getCurrentColor() {
        return currentColor;
    }
}
```

Test main class.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class STTestMain extends JFrame {
    STDrawingArea drawingArea = new STDrawingArea();
    public STTestMain()
    {
        //JFrame settings
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Spelling Trainer");
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);


        //Panel of buttons
        JPanel buttonContainer = new JPanel();
        JButton btnPenColor = new JButton("Red Pen");

        buttonContainer.add(btnPenColor);
        //Drawing Area instantiation


        //Adding things to JFrame
        getContentPane().add(drawingArea);
        getContentPane().add(buttonContainer,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        pack();


        //button listener
        btnPenColor.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                drawingArea.changePenColor(Color.RED);
            }
        });
    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        STTestMain test = new STTestMain();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way:

- Use your ArrayList to draw the current curve as it is being drawn, but
- Use a BufferedImage to draw your completed curves
- You would do this on mouseReleased and would draw the current curve to the BufferedImage using the current color.
- You'll also need to re-initialize your ArrayList of points after drawing to the BufferedImage.
- Don't forget to dispose of the BufferedImage's Graphics object after you're done using it.
- Draw the BufferedImage in your paintComponent method after super.paintComponent but before drawing your current curve.
- This way when you change the color of your drawing, only the current curve is effected.

**EDIT**
You've mentioned in a comment that you're not familiar with BufferedImage, and are looking for another way. I suppose you could create a class that holds an ArrayList of Points together with a Color, and then on each mouseReleased create an object of this class and add it to an ArrayList in your drawing panel. Then your paintComponent method could iterate through that ArrayList, drawing the list of Points with their associated color, but my gut tells me that you're an intelligent guy and that you'd pick up on how to use a BufferedImage in no time. I really think it's the best solution.  And if you try it and it flops, show us your code, and we'll likely be able to help you.

**EDIT 2**
The BufferedImage constructor will need the image width, height and an image type -- something I'm not 100% familiar with. I usually use BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB for general purpose drawing, and BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB for general purpose that needs an alpha too. Then you'll extract a Graphics object out of the BufferedImage, say getGraphics() if all you need is a Graphics object and not a Graphics2D object. Then when you initialize the BufferedImage in your constructor, fill it with a Color.white, just as you for your JPanel. Then dispose the Graphics object.  Then each time you want to draw, you getGraphics, draw with it, just like you do in the paintComponent method, dispose of the Graphics when done, and finally draw the BufferedImage in the paintComponent via the drawImage method.

**EDIT 3**
Example program that doesn't do quite what you are trying to do but does illustrate use of a BufferedImage with drawing.  This program changes the color each time a new path or curve is drawn.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;

public class STTestSimple {
   private static void createAndShowUI() {
      STDrawPanel drawPanel = new STDrawPanel();
      STMouseAdapter mAdapter = new STMouseAdapter(drawPanel);
      drawPanel.addMouseListener(mAdapter);
      drawPanel.addMouseMotionListener(mAdapter);

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Drawing");
      frame.getContentPane().add(drawPanel);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setResizable(false);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowUI();
         }
      });
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class STDrawPanel extends JPanel {
   private static final int ST_WIDTH = 700;
   private static final int ST_HEIGHT = 500;
   private static final Color BACKGROUND_COLOR = Color.white;
   private static final float STROKE_WIDTH = 6f;
   private static final Stroke STROKE = new BasicStroke(STROKE_WIDTH,
            BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND);
   private static final Color[] colors = {Color.black, Color.blue, Color.red,
      Color.green, Color.orange, Color.MAGENTA};

   private BufferedImage bImage = new BufferedImage(ST_WIDTH, ST_HEIGHT,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
   private Color color = Color.black;
   private ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
   private int colorIndex = 0;

   public STDrawPanel() {
      Graphics g = bImage.getGraphics();
      g.setColor(BACKGROUND_COLOR);
      g.fillRect(0, 0, ST_WIDTH, ST_HEIGHT);
      g.dispose();
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.drawImage(bImage, 0, 0, null);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      drawCurve(g2);
   }

   private void addCurveToBufferedImage() {
      Graphics2D g2 = bImage.createGraphics();
      drawCurve(g2);
      g2.dispose();
   }

   private void drawCurve(Graphics2D g2) {
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
               RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      g2.setStroke(STROKE);
      g2.setColor(color);
      if (points != null && points.size() > 1) {
         for (int i = 0; i < points.size() - 1; i++) {
            int x1 = points.get(i).x;
            int y1 = points.get(i).y;
            int x2 = points.get(i + 1).x;
            int y2 = points.get(i + 1).y;
            g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
         }
      }
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(ST_WIDTH, ST_HEIGHT);
   }

   public void curveStart(Point point) {
      points.clear();
      points.add(point);
   }

   public void curveEnd(Point point) {
      points.add(point);
      addCurveToBufferedImage();
      points.clear();
      repaint();

      colorIndex++;
      colorIndex %= colors.length;
      setColor(colors[colorIndex]);
   }

   public void curveAdd(Point point) {
      points.add(point);
      repaint();
   }

   public void setColor(Color color) {
      this.color = color;
   }
}

class STMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
   private STDrawPanel drawPanel;

   public STMouseAdapter(STDrawPanel drawPanel) {
      this.drawPanel = drawPanel;
   }

   @Override
   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
      drawPanel.curveStart(e.getPoint());
   }

   @Override
   public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
      drawPanel.curveEnd(e.getPoint());
   }

   @Override
   public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
      drawPanel.curveAdd(e.getPoint());
   }
}
```

Comment: hi, sorry but i have no experience with working on bufferedimage before, as im still inexperienced, is there another way of doing it?

Comment: @kyrogue: please see Edit in my answer above.

Comment: i have read that the bufferedImage constructor will take in a image type? however my JPanel drawings are not images, it is just drawing of freehand lines, how does this link up

Comment: The BufferedImage constructor will need the image width, height and an image type -- something I'm not 100% familiar with. I usually use BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB for general purpose drawing, and BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB for general purpose that needs an alpha too.

Comment: @kyrogue: I've posted example code using BufferedImage. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

[Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) gives two ideas on how you might do this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks hovercraft, i've done it looking at your code and fiddling around lol.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class STDrawingArea extends JPanel {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final int DA_WIDTH = 700;
    private static final int DA_HEIGHT = 500;
    private static final Color DA_BGCOLOR = Color.WHITE;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();

    private Color currentColor;
    BufferedImage bImage = new BufferedImage(DA_WIDTH, DA_HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    public STDrawingArea()
    {
         setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

         //Basic Settings for bImage
         Graphics g2d = bImage.getGraphics();
         g2d.setColor(DA_BGCOLOR);
         g2d.fillRect(0, 0, DA_WIDTH, DA_HEIGHT);
         g2d.dispose();

         addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
             public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
             {
                points.clear();
                points.add(e.getPoint());
             }
         });

         addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) 
            {
                points.add(e.getPoint());
                repaint();
            }

             }); 

         addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
             public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
             {
                 points.add(e.getPoint());
                 points.clear();
                 System.out.println("mouseReleased X: "+e.getX()+"mouseReleased Y: "+e.getY());
                 repaint();
             }
         });
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(DA_WIDTH,DA_HEIGHT);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        drawIntoBufferedImage();
        g.drawImage(bImage,0,0,null);
        freehandLines(g);

    }
    public void drawIntoBufferedImage()
    {
        Graphics g = bImage.getGraphics();
        freehandLines(g);
        g.dispose();
    }

    public void freehandLines(Graphics g)
    {
         if(points != null && points.size() > 1)
         {

             g.setColor(getCurrentColor());
              for(int i = 0; i < points.size()-1;i++)
               {
                   int x1 = points.get(i).x;
                   int y1 = points.get(i).y;
                   int x2 = points.get(i+1).x;
                   int y2 = points.get(i+1).y;
                   g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
               }
         }
    }
    //clear drawings method
    public void clearDrawings()
    {
        if(points!=null)
        {
            points.clear();
            Graphics g = bImage.getGraphics();
            g.setColor(DA_BGCOLOR);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, DA_WIDTH, DA_WIDTH);
            g.dispose();
            repaint();
        }

    }

    public void setCurrentColor(Color currentColor) {
        if(currentColor == null)
        {
            currentColor = Color.BLACK;
        }else{
            this.currentColor = currentColor;
        }

    }

    public Color getCurrentColor() {
        if (currentColor == null)
        return Color.BLACK;
        else
        return currentColor;
    }
}
```

main class

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class STTestMain extends JFrame {
    STDrawingArea drawingArea = new STDrawingArea();
    public STTestMain()
    {
        //JFrame settings
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Spelling Trainer");
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);


        //Panel of buttons
        JPanel buttonContainer = new JPanel();
        JButton btnRedPen = new JButton("Red Pen");
        JButton btnGreenPen = new JButton("Green Pen");
        JButton btnClear = new JButton("Clear");
        buttonContainer.add(btnRedPen);
        buttonContainer.add(btnGreenPen);
        buttonContainer.add(btnClear);
        //Drawing Area instantiation


        //Adding things to JFrame
        getContentPane().add(drawingArea);
        getContentPane().add(buttonContainer,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        pack();


        //button listener
        btnRedPen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                drawingArea.setCurrentColor(Color.RED);
            }
        });

        btnGreenPen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                drawingArea.setCurrentColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
        });

        btnClear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                drawingArea.clearDrawings();
            }
        });
    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        STTestMain test = new STTestMain();
    }

}
```