# Drawing a rectangle that won't disappear in next paint

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, paint

I trying to create a JPanel that draws rectangles. The Panel needs to draw alot of rectangles, but they dont move.
One solution to my problem was to create an list with all the rectangles i already created and draw they all in every call of "Paint". But there is a lot of rectangles and it slows the computer.
I also tried to use repaint(x, y, height, width) to rapaint just the space of the new rectangle but it did not work. (JPanel keeps erasing previous rectangles.)
In sort, i need to draw rectangles that wont disappear every paint. Or a paint method that wont erase previous draws, or wont paint the background.
That is part of my JPanel class:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel{
  private int x, y, size;
  private Color c;
  public void DrawRect(int x, int y, int size, Color c){
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.size = size;
      this.c = c;
      repaint();
  }
  @Override
    public void
    paint(Graphics g) {

        g.setColor(c);
      g.fillRect(x, y, size, size);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Don't override `paint` WITHOUT VERY, VERY good reason...use `paintComponent` instead
2. Always call `super.paintXxx`, these methods do a lot in the background, failing to call super is only going to come back and haunt you.
3. If you're using multiple panes as rectangles, make the `MyPanel` transparent.

Paint's are stateless.  There is no connection between the last paint and the next.  On each paint request you are expected to update the entire state.

Andrew's suggest of double buffering (or back buffering) is and excellent one, and I highly encourage you to have a look an implementing it.

In the mean time, I put this little example together...

[image]

Basically, you press and hold the mouse button and it will randomly add another rectangle to the panel every 40 milli-seconds (roughly 25 frames a second).

I got this up to a 1000 rects without any issue, was able to resize the window without and issue or obviously slow down...

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    private List<MyRectangle> lstShapes;
    private Timer populate;

    public MyPanel() {

        lstShapes = new ArrayList<MyRectangle>(25);

        populate = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                int x = (int) (Math.random() * getWidth());
                int y = (int) (Math.random() * getHeight());
                int width = (int) (Math.random() * (getWidth() / 4));
                int height = (int) (Math.random() * (getHeight() / 4));

                if (x + width > getWidth()) {
                    x = getWidth() - width;
                }
                if (y + height > getHeight()) {
                    y = getHeight() - height;
                }

                Color color = new Color(
                        (int) (Math.random() * 255),
                        (int) (Math.random() * 255),
                        (int) (Math.random() * 255));

                lstShapes.add(new MyRectangle(x, y, width, height, color));
                repaint();
            }
        });
        populate.setInitialDelay(0);
        populate.setRepeats(true);
        populate.setCoalesce(true);

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                populate.restart();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                populate.stop();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        for (MyRectangle rect : lstShapes) {
            rect.paint(g2d);
        }

        FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
        String text = Integer.toString(lstShapes.size());

        g2d.setColor(getForeground());
        g2d.drawString(text, getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(text), getHeight() - fm.getHeight() + fm.getAscent());

    }

    public class MyRectangle extends Rectangle {

        private Color color;

        public MyRectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color color) {
            super(x, y, width, height);
            this.color = color;
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public void paint(Graphics2D g2d) {

            g2d.setColor(getColor());
            g2d.fill(this);

        }
    }
}
```

have a go, it's fun ;)

ps- I got to up to over 5000 rectangles before I noticed a slow down (I modified the code down to a 10 milli second delay and was adding 10 new rectangles per tick)

Comment: @ViniciusTafuriCarvalho you're welcome, had fun putting it together

Answer (score 14):

Start with this approach - based around a `BufferedImage` as the painting surface..

[image: Basic paint app.]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.RenderingHints.Key;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class BasicPaint {

    /** Reference to the original image. */
    private BufferedImage originalImage;
    /** Image used to make changes. */
    private BufferedImage canvasImage;
    /** The main GUI that might be added to a frame or applet. */
    private JPanel gui;
    /** The color to use when calling clear, text or other 
     * drawing functionality. */
    private Color color = Color.WHITE;
    /** General user messages. */
    private JLabel output = new JLabel("You DooDoodle!");

    private BufferedImage colorSample = new BufferedImage(
            16,16,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    private JLabel imageLabel;
    private int activeTool;
    public static final int SELECTION_TOOL = 0;
    public static final int DRAW_TOOL = 1;
    public static final int TEXT_TOOL = 2;

    private Point selectionStart; 
    private Rectangle selection;
    private boolean dirty = false;
    private Stroke stroke = new BasicStroke(
            3,BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND,BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND,1.7f);
    private RenderingHints renderingHints;

    public JComponent getGui() {
        if (gui==null) {
            Map<Key, Object> hintsMap = new HashMap<RenderingHints.Key,Object>();
            hintsMap.put(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            hintsMap.put(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
            hintsMap.put(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            renderingHints = new RenderingHints(hintsMap); 

            setImage(new BufferedImage(320,240,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB));
            gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4,4));
            gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5,3,5,3));

            JPanel imageView = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            imageView.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(480,320));
            imageLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(canvasImage));
            JScrollPane imageScroll = new JScrollPane(imageView);
            imageView.add(imageLabel);
            imageLabel.addMouseMotionListener(new ImageMouseMotionListener());
            imageLabel.addMouseListener(new ImageMouseListener());
            gui.add(imageScroll,BorderLayout.CENTER);

            JToolBar tb = new JToolBar();
            tb.setFloatable(false);
            JButton colorButton = new JButton("Color");
            colorButton.setMnemonic('o');
            colorButton.setToolTipText("Choose a Color");
            ActionListener colorListener = new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    Color c = JColorChooser.showDialog(
                            gui, "Choose a color", color);
                    if (c!=null) {
                        setColor(c);
                    }
                }
            };
            colorButton.addActionListener(colorListener);
            colorButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(colorSample));
            tb.add(colorButton);

            setColor(color);

            final SpinnerNumberModel strokeModel = 
                    new SpinnerNumberModel(3,1,16,1);
            JSpinner strokeSize = new JSpinner(strokeModel);
            ChangeListener strokeListener = new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
                    Object o = strokeModel.getValue();
                    Integer i = (Integer)o; 
                    stroke = new BasicStroke(
                            i.intValue(),
                            BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND,
                            BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND,
                            1.7f);
                }
            };
            strokeSize.addChangeListener(strokeListener);
            strokeSize.setMaximumSize(strokeSize.getPreferredSize());
            JLabel strokeLabel = new JLabel("Stroke");
            strokeLabel.setLabelFor(strokeSize);
            strokeLabel.setDisplayedMnemonic('t');
            tb.add(strokeLabel);
            tb.add(strokeSize);

            tb.addSeparator();

            ActionListener clearListener = new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    int result = JOptionPane.OK_OPTION;
                    if (dirty) {
                        result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                                gui, "Erase the current painting?");
                    }
                    if (result==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                        clear(canvasImage);
                    }
                }
            };
            JButton clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
            tb.add(clearButton);
            clearButton.addActionListener(clearListener);

            gui.add(tb, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

            JToolBar tools = new JToolBar(JToolBar.VERTICAL);
            tools.setFloatable(false);
            JButton crop = new JButton("Crop");
            final JRadioButton select = new JRadioButton("Select", true);
            final JRadioButton draw = new JRadioButton("Draw");
            final JRadioButton text = new JRadioButton("Text");

            tools.add(crop);            
            tools.add(select);          
            tools.add(draw);            
            tools.add(text);

            ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
            bg.add(select);
            bg.add(text);
            bg.add(draw);
            ActionListener toolGroupListener = new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    if (ae.getSource()==select) {
                        activeTool = SELECTION_TOOL;
                    } else if (ae.getSource()==draw) {
                        activeTool = DRAW_TOOL;
                    } else if (ae.getSource()==text) {
                        activeTool = TEXT_TOOL;
                    }
                }
            };
            select.addActionListener(toolGroupListener);
            draw.addActionListener(toolGroupListener);
            text.addActionListener(toolGroupListener);

            gui.add(tools, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

            gui.add(output,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
            clear(colorSample);
            clear(canvasImage);
        }

        return gui;
    }

    /** Clears the entire image area by painting it with the current color. */
    public void clear(BufferedImage bi) {
        Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHints(renderingHints);
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight());

        g.dispose();
        imageLabel.repaint();
    }

    public void setImage(BufferedImage image) {
        this.originalImage = image;
        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight();
        canvasImage = new BufferedImage(w,h,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics2D g = this.canvasImage.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHints(renderingHints);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, gui);
        g.dispose();

        selection = new Rectangle(0,0,w,h); 
        if (this.imageLabel!=null) {
            imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(canvasImage));
            this.imageLabel.repaint();
        }
        if (gui!=null) {
            gui.invalidate();
        }
    }

    /** Set the current painting color and refresh any elements needed. */
    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
        clear(colorSample);
    }

    private JMenu getFileMenu(boolean webstart){
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        file.setMnemonic('f');

        JMenuItem newImageItem = new JMenuItem("New");
        newImageItem.setMnemonic('n');
        ActionListener newImage = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
                        360, 300, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                clear(bi);
                setImage(bi);
            }
        };
        newImageItem.addActionListener(newImage);
        file.add(newImageItem);

        if (webstart) {
            //TODO Add open/save functionality using JNLP API
        } else {
            //TODO Add save functionality using J2SE API
            file.addSeparator();
            ActionListener openListener = new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    if (!dirty) {
                        JFileChooser ch = getFileChooser();
                        int result = ch.showOpenDialog(gui);
                        if (result==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ) {
                            try {
                                BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(
                                        ch.getSelectedFile());
                                setImage(bi);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                showError(e);
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        // TODO
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                                gui, "TODO - prompt save image..");
                    }
                }
            };
            JMenuItem openItem = new JMenuItem("Open");
            openItem.setMnemonic('o');
            openItem.addActionListener(openListener);
            file.add(openItem);

            ActionListener saveListener = new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JFileChooser ch = getFileChooser();
                    int result = ch.showSaveDialog(gui);
                    if (result==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ) {
                        try {
                            File f = ch.getSelectedFile();
                            ImageIO.write(BasicPaint.this.canvasImage, "png", f);
                            BasicPaint.this.originalImage = BasicPaint.this.canvasImage;
                            dirty = false;
                        } catch (IOException ioe) {
                            showError(ioe);
                            ioe.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            JMenuItem saveItem = new JMenuItem("Save");
            saveItem.addActionListener(saveListener);
            saveItem.setMnemonic('s');
            file.add(saveItem);
        }

        if (canExit()) {
            ActionListener exit = new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            };
            JMenuItem exitItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
            exitItem.setMnemonic('x');
            file.addSeparator();
            exitItem.addActionListener(exit);
            file.add(exitItem);
        }

        return file;
    }

    private void showError(Throwable t) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                gui, 
                t.getMessage(), 
                t.toString(), 
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    JFileChooser chooser = null;

    public JFileChooser getFileChooser() {
        if (chooser==null) {
            chooser = new JFileChooser();
            FileFilter ff = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Image files", ImageIO.getReaderFileSuffixes());
            chooser.setFileFilter(ff);
        }
        return chooser;

    }

    public boolean canExit() {
        boolean canExit = false;
        SecurityManager sm = System.getSecurityManager();
        if (sm==null) {
            canExit = true;
        } else {
            try {
                sm.checkExit(0);
                canExit = true; 
            } catch(Exception stayFalse) {
            }
        }

        return canExit;
    }

    public JMenuBar getMenuBar(boolean webstart){
        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        mb.add(this.getFileMenu(webstart));
        return mb;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                            UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // use default
                }
                BasicPaint bp = new BasicPaint();

                JFrame f = new JFrame("DooDoodle!");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(bp.getGui());
                f.setJMenuBar(bp.getMenuBar(false));

                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }

    public void text(Point point) {
        String text = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(gui, "Text to add", "Text");
        if (text!=null) {
            Graphics2D g = this.canvasImage.createGraphics();
            g.setRenderingHints(renderingHints);
            g.setColor(this.color);
            g.setStroke(stroke);
            int n = 0;
            g.drawString(text,point.x,point.y);
            g.dispose();
            this.imageLabel.repaint();
        }
    }

    public void draw(Point point) {
        Graphics2D g = this.canvasImage.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHints(renderingHints);
        g.setColor(this.color);
        g.setStroke(stroke);
        int n = 0;
        g.drawLine(point.x, point.y, point.x+n, point.y+n);
        g.dispose();
        this.imageLabel.repaint();
    }

    class ImageMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (activeTool==BasicPaint.SELECTION_TOOL) {
                selectionStart = arg0.getPoint();
            } else if (activeTool==BasicPaint.DRAW_TOOL) {
                // TODO
                draw(arg0.getPoint());
            } else if (activeTool==BasicPaint.TEXT_TOOL) {
                // TODO
                text(arg0.getPoint());
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                        gui, 
                        "Application error.  :(", 
                        "Error!", 
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
            if (activeTool==BasicPaint.SELECTION_TOOL) {
                selection = new Rectangle(
                        selectionStart.x,
                        selectionStart.y,
                        arg0.getPoint().x,
                        arg0.getPoint().y);
            }
        }
    }

    class ImageMouseMotionListener implements MouseMotionListener {

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
            reportPositionAndColor(arg0);
            if (activeTool==BasicPaint.SELECTION_TOOL) {
                selection = new Rectangle(
                        selectionStart.x,
                        selectionStart.y,
                        arg0.getPoint().x-selectionStart.x,
                        arg0.getPoint().y-selectionStart.y);
            } else if (activeTool==BasicPaint.DRAW_TOOL) {
                draw(arg0.getPoint());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
            reportPositionAndColor(arg0);
        }

    }

    private void reportPositionAndColor(MouseEvent me) {
        String text = "";
        if (activeTool==BasicPaint.SELECTION_TOOL) {
            text += "Selection (X,Y:WxH): " + 
                    (int)selection.getX() +
                    "," +
                    (int)selection.getY() +
                    ":" +
                    (int)selection.getWidth() +
                    "x" +
                    (int)selection.getHeight();
        } else {
            text += "X,Y: " + (me.getPoint().x+1) + "," + (me.getPoint().y+1);
        }
        output.setText(text);
    }
}
```

This source is very patchy.

- It has many parts with `// TODO`
- A `dirty` attribute is declared but never used in any meaningful way.  ..