# Word wrapping in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I have a word wrapping issue when using JTextPane.  I think it's my IDE (JCreator)  but when i use the source everyone else is using I get several errors.  Sorry for the line breaks...  Could it be my IDE or can someone please let me know the right way of doing this. TIA -Roland

The source I am using can be found at http://java-sl.com/tip_html_letter_wrap.html

**lol.. I forgot the space!  Thanks all.  It is going to proceed.  I have been programming all night and am a little groggy.  Best of luck -Roland**

```
> --------------------Configuration: inigui - JDK version <Default> - <Default>--------------------
> C:\ucdhb2\gaia\inigui\inigui2\src\inigui.java:283: error: ')' expected
>               gentextp.setEditorKit( newHTMLEditorKit(){ 
>                                                        ^ C:\ucdhb2\gaia\inigui\inigui2\src\inigui.java:285: error: ';' expected
>            public ViewFactory getViewFactory(){ 
>                                             ^ C:\ucdhb2\gaia\inigui\inigui2\src\inigui.java:330: error: illegal
> start of type
>         }); 
>          ^ C:\ucdhb2\gaia\inigui\inigui2\src\inigui.java:337: error: <identifier> expected
>         panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
>                        ^ C:\ucdhb2\gaia\inigui\inigui2\src\inigui.java:337: error: illegal
> start of type
>         panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
>                         ^ C:\ucdhb2\gaia\inigui\inigui2\src\inigui.java:337: error: ')' expected
>         panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
>                            ^ C:\ucdhb2\gaia\inigui\inigui2\src\inigui.java:337: error: ';' expected
>         panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
>                                       ^ C:\ucdhb2\gaia\inigui\inigui2\src\inigui.java:337: error: illegal
> start of type
>         panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
>                                        ^ C:\ucdhb2\gaia\inigui\inigui2\src\inigui.java:337: error: <identifier>
> expected
>         panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
>                                         ^ C:\ucdhb2\gaia\inigui\inigui2\src\inigui.java:337: error: ';' expected
>         panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
>                                          ^ C:\ucdhb2\gaia\inigui\inigui2\src\inigui.java:337: error: illegal
> start of type
>         panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
>                                            ^ C:\ucdhb2\gaia\inigui\inigui2\src\inigui.java:337: error: <identifier>
> expected
>         panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
>                                             ^ C:\ucdhb2\gaia\inigui\inigui2\src\inigui.java:339: error: illegal
> start of type
>         return panel;
>         ^ C:\ucdhb2\gaia\inigui\inigui2\src\inigui.java:339: error: ';' expected
>         return panel;
>               ^ C:\ucdhb2\gaia\inigui\inigui2\src\inigui.java:341: error: class, interface, or enum expected }  ^ 15 errors
```

Comment: Use code formatting on code rather than quote formatting!  I changed it to code formatting but could not be bothered removing the `> ` prefixes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The linked code needs space chars in 3 places to compile.

E.G.

```
final JEditorPane htmlTextPane = newJEditorPane();
```

should be:

```
final JEditorPane htmlTextPane = new JEditorPane();
```

Look at the line numbers identified by the compiler for the others.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a white space after the `new` keyword:

```
gentextp.setEditorKit( newHTMLEditorKit(){
```

should be

```
gentextp.setEditorKit( new HTMLEditorKit(){
```

See how syntax coloring changes between the two?

Comment: Beat me by 15 seconds.  +1  As an aside I think it is very funky how the script that formats code snippets can show that problem more clearly.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried the linked source myself and it work fine (Eclipse)

However, based on the error message you pasted here, you are clearly not using (exactly) using this code.

Apparently, your compiler has issues on the following lines:

C:\ucdhb2\gaia\inigui\inigui2\src\inigui.java:283
C:\ucdhb2\gaia\inigui\inigui2\src\inigui.java:285
...

I recommend to revise the correct usage of the brackets, semicolons, etc.

If you still have issues, please post YOUR code.