# Visual Artifacts appearing on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, repaint, paintcomponent

I am trying to create a program with 2 `JPanel` using `BorderLayout`. The center panel is for random drawing of rectangle while the south panel is for the buttons.

I am getting a weird image of the button on the top left corner of the `JFrame` whenever I hover the mouse cursor over the North or South button. I did some research and found out that this could be the reason for having a transparent background. I tried using `super.paintComponent(g)` for the panel but the rest of the rectangles drawn earlier disappear. I need the rectangles to stay in the `JPanel` but not the weird image on the top left.

I don't know what I am doing wrong, hopefully someone can help or give some clue on how to solve this problem.

```
    public class TwoBRandomRec extends JFrame{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TwoBRandomRec rec = new TwoBRandomRec();

        rec.setSize(500,500);
        rec.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        rec.setVisible(true);
    }

    public TwoBRandomRec() {
        //Create the buttons
        JButton north = new JButton("North");
        JButton south = new JButton("South");
        DrawPanel drawPanel = new DrawPanel(500,500);

        JPanel southP = new JPanel();
        southP.add(south);
        southP.add(north);

        this.add(drawPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(southP, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        this.setTitle("TwoButtonRandomRec");
        this.pack();        
    }

    public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private Random rand = new Random();
        private int x,y,xSize,ySize;
        private int height,width;

        public DrawPanel(int w,int h) {
            width = w;
            height = h;
        }
        public void RandomX(){
             x=rand.nextInt(width-1);
             xSize=rand.nextInt(width-x);
         }

         public void RandomY(){
             y=rand.nextInt(height-1);
             ySize=rand.nextInt(height-y);
         }

         public Color RandomColour(){
             rand.nextInt(height);
             return new Color(rand.nextInt(255),rand.nextInt(255),rand.nextInt(255));
         }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            RandomX();
            RandomY();

            g.setColor(RandomColour());
            g.fillRect(x, y, xSize, ySize);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {  
            }

            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not calling `super.paintComponent`

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g); // <-- Insert me here and watch problem go away
    RandomX();
    RandomY();

    g.setColor(RandomColour());
    g.fillRect(x, y, xSize, ySize);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(50); // <-- This is an INCREDIBLY bad idea, NEVER, EVER do this

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {  
    }

    repaint(); // <-- This is a bad idea, watch CPU max out...
}
```

You are obligated to call `super.paintComponent` to ensure that the paint chain is upheld correctly and things like opacity and cleaning up of the graphics context takes place.

The `Graphics` object is shared between components through a single repaint pass, failure to honor the correct paint chain will result in, well, problems like yours

Never update the UI in anyway from any `paint` method (this includes calling `repaint`), this is just causing your `paint` method to be recalled, over and over and over...until you CPU hits 100% and program hangs.

Never, EVER do any time consuming or block operations within the `paint` methods (or the UI generally), this will make it look like the program as hung and make the users upset (you think zombi hordes are bad :P).  Blocking in this way prevents the EDT from responding to paint requests...

I'd recommend having a read through:

- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help! However, the super.paintComponent(g) clears my entire screen. I need the previously drawn rectangles to appear as well. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Each repaint is required to re-render its contents, from scratch, this ensures that the component is properly up-to-date regardless of why the repaint was requested. You are going to have to maintain a list of all the rectangles and repaint them on each pass. Alternatively, you can paint to an off screen buffer and simply paint that to the acreen inatead. This is how painting works

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683533/drawing-a-rectangle-that-wont-disappear-in-next-paint/12683601#12683601 for an example

Comment: that is exactly what I am looking for! I have been cracking my head for this over the past few days! Thanks you so much for all the references. Much appreciated!