# How to move all the content of a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jpanel, graphics2d

I have a class that inherits from `JPanel`. It is called `DrawingPanel` and in this class I draw lines and shapes using `Graphics2D` and I use the position of user's mouse to do some operations on these shapes.

The drawings in the panel can take a lot of space on screen (for instance I may draw lines from (-200, -300) to (2000, 1000)), so actually I only see a part of the drawings. That's why I would like to be able to move all things drawn in my panel with scrolling.

Is there a simple and elegant solution to do this, and that would not require too much changes in my code?

EDIT: Actually my problem is that I don't know an elegant way to have scrolling working in a `JPanel` with shapes drawn with `Graphics2D`. I tried to add my `JPanel` to a `JScrollPane` but it did not worked. Practically, what should I have to add to my code?

Comment: "That's why I would like to be able to move all things drawn in my JPanel with scrolling." Is this not what scrolling does essentially? Move the viewport to different area of canvas? It's like physics relativity, the viewport moving is the same as the shapes moving.

Comment: I think the most elegant solution is to either: a) Start with a `BufferedImage` of defined size (range & scale) and display it in a label in a scroll pane or b) return a preferred size for the drawn panel that reflects the entire extent of the X/Y range, and transform (translate to fit) the graphics when drawn (then display it in a scroll pane).

Comment: @AndrewThompson DooDoodle
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683533/drawing-a-rectangle-that-wont-disappear-in-next-paint/12683632#12683632 would be a good example! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your drawing code in a separate method, called (for example) `draw` which takes 1 argument, a Graphics object.
In the `paintComponent` method you `translate()` the Graphics object according tonwhoch area of the drawing should be shown and then pass it into your `draw` method.

Comment: It's a shame I did not think about this solution before :) It worked perfectly. Thanks.