# Add image to panel not using swings

Tags: java, image, awt, bufferedimage, java-2d

how to we add bitmap image in panel and then get the graphics that the image is using and tell the panel to draw a line using the same graphics inside the image.

Comment: You want to edit the image? Maybe save the results?

Comment: no nothing of that sort..jst want to do the above mentioned thing

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683533/drawing-a-rectangle-that-wont-disappear-in-next-paint/12683632#12683632) for a starting point (although it is a bit long).

Comment: i was new to this site..atleast ppl shud comment before closing questions

Answer (score 2):

Basic painting is done by a Swing components `paintComponent` method.

The best choice you have is to load the image using the `ImageIO` API...

```
BufferedImage image;

public void loadImage() throws IOException {
    image = ImageIO.read(...);
    // ImageIO can read a image from a file or a URL or a ImageInputStream
}
```

Then simply paint the image...

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    // Now you can continue drawing ontop of it...
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.drawLine(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
}
```

You might like to have a read of

- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Working with Images](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html)