# How do I add and not repaint drawings in a JApplet in java?

Tags: java, swing, draw, java-2d, japplet

How do I add a drawing ii a Japplet and not replace it with a new one? I am using repaint() but all it does is replace my existing rectangle. What would be the right codes to add another rectangle and not replace it?

Say I have this code: ( This code is not mine )

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;

public class MoveBox extends Applet
{
   private int x = 20, y = 20;
   private int width = 10, height = 10;
   private int inc = 5;
   private Color myColor = Color.red;

   private Button up = new Button("Up");
   private Button down = new Button("Down");
   private Button left = new Button("Left");
   private Button right = new Button("Right");
   private Button increase = new Button("[+]");
   private Button decrease = new Button("[-]");

   // init method
   public void init()
   {
      Panel buttons = new Panel();
      buttons.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      buttons.add(up);
      buttons.add(down);
      buttons.add(left);
      buttons.add(right);
      buttons.add(increase);
      buttons.add(decrease);

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add("South", buttons);
   }
   // public methods
   public boolean action(Event e, Object o)
   {
      if (e.target == up)
         return handleUp();
      else if (e.target == down)
         return handleDown();
      else if (e.target == left)
         return handleLeft();
      else if (e.target == right)
         return handleRight();
      else if (e.target == increase)
         return handleIncrease();
      else if (e.target == decrease)
         return handleDecrease();
      else
         return super.action(e, o);
   }
   public void paint(Graphics g)
   {
      g.setColor(myColor);
      g.fillRect(x,y,width,height);
   }
   // private methods
   private boolean handleUp()
   {
      y = y - inc;
      repaint();
      return true;
   }
   private boolean handleDown()
   {
      y = y + inc;
      repaint();
      return true;
   }
   private boolean handleRight()
   {
      if (x < size().width)
         x = x + inc;
      else
         x = 0;
      repaint();
      return true;
   }
   private boolean handleLeft()
   {
      if (x > 0)
         x = x - inc;
      else
         x = size().width;
      repaint();
      return true;
   }
   private boolean handleIncrease()
   {
      width += 5;
      height += 5;
      repaint();
      return true;
   }
   private boolean handleDecrease()
   {
      if (width > 5)
      {
         width -= 5;
         height -= 5;
      }
      repaint();
      return true;
   }
}
```

How do I add another rectangle when I press the buttons, up, down, left and right?

Answer (score 3):

Paint to a `BufferedImage` and display it in a `JLabel`.  When it is updated, call `label.repaint()` to see the changes.  E.G. as seen in [Do Doodle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12683632/418556).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Store the things you want to paint in a collection (for example, the coordinates of your two rectangles), call `repaint()`, and have your `paintComponent()` method iterate through the collection of things to paint and paint them one by one.

Comment: I'm really sorry sir! I'm really new to Japplet so I slightly didn't understand your answer. How do I store the things I want in a collection?

Comment: For example, you create a Rectangle class containing x, y, width and height fields, and you create a `List<Rectangle>`.

Comment: Thank you sir! I'll be trying that. :D

Answer (score 1):

- see [lesson Java Applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/index.html)
- put there [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) and before that to see [lesson 2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)
- easier could be start with plain [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html)