# How do you make a graphics program?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I'm coding a project in java.  I have a really basic question: how do you get a graphics program? And what libraries do you need?

I know that Processing (which isn't really java) does this for you, but I'm using eclipse.

Comment: This question depends on the meaning of *"graphics program"*

Comment: By graphics program, I mean how to get a render window.

Comment: You could start taking a look at something like [How to make a UI in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: This is much too broad a question for SO.  There are many ways to "make a graphics program", a phrase which is ambiguous at best.  SO is for specific programming questions that can be succinctly answered; your question is open to debate and discussion.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683533/drawing-a-rectangle-that-wont-disappear-in-next-paint/12683632#12683632) for a simple paint program.

Answer (score 2):

For desktop apps you should look at Swing, Java2D, and Java3D.

The web is another matter.  Your browser choices should include JavaScript libraries like d3.

Eclipse has nothing to do with it.  It's just an IDE.

Comment: *cough* JavaFX *cough*

Comment: Is that dead technology still alive?

Comment: By accounts from Oracle, it's meant to be a replacement for Swing :(

Comment: It's not what Oracle says that counts, it's what the marketplace decides.  See Silverlight for similar fate.