# drawing an oval after clicking the mouse

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paintcomponent

I want to draw an oval when I click the mouse in my panel. And drawing is allowed after I click the button. But a problem is occurs: a copy of the button is drawn in the top left of the panel.

This is my code:

```
 public class PaintPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{

        private boolean draw = false;
        private JButton button;
        private Point myPoint;
        public PaintPanel(){
            this.setSize(800,600);
            button = new JButton("Allow draw");
            button.setSize(30,30);
            this.add(button);
            this.addMouseListener(this);
            this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    draw = true;

                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            g.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,24));
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            if(draw){
                g.drawOval(myPoint.x-10, myPoint.y-10, 20, 20);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if(draw){
                myPoint = e.getPoint();
                repaint();
            }
        }
        public static void main(String[] agrs){
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Painting on panel");
            frame.add(new PaintPanel());
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setSize(800,600);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Swing apps should be run from the EDT. See [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

You broke the paint chain.

Add `super.paintComponent(g)` before you do any custom painting

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,24));
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    if(draw){
        g.drawOval(myPoint.x-10, myPoint.y-10, 20, 20);
    }
}
```

`Graphics` is a shared resource.  It is provided to everything that is painted within a given paint cycle, meaning, that unless you clear it first, it will contain other things that have already been painted before you.

One of the jobs of `paintComponent` is to prepare the `Graphics` context for painting, but clearing it (filling it with the components background color)

Take a closer look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details

Comment: I want to draw append. previos oval doesn't disappear

Comment: Then add them to some kind of `List` and repaint them when `paintComponent` is called.  Painting in Swing is a destructive process, this is how the API works, you need to work within it.

Comment: _"I want to draw append. previos oval doesn't disappear "_. @hjepsjga_94 see [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22123304/2587435) in regards to MadProgrammer's point about the `List`

Comment: @hjepsjga_94 For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683533/drawing-a-rectangle-that-wont-disappear-in-next-paint/12683601#12683601)

Answer (score 1):

> I want to draw append. previos oval doesn't disappear

See [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for the two common ways to do incremental painting:

1. Keep a List of all the objects you want to paint and then iterate through this List in the paintComponent() method of your component
2. Use a BufferedImage and draw your objects on the BufferedImage and then just paint the BufferedImage in your paintComponent() method.