# Java Mutithreading Ball Animation

Tags: java, multithreading

My issue here with ball animation is that the ball is moving in a straight line leaving behind a trail. My expected output is that there should be no trail of the ball.

The code determines the movement of the ball in just one direction along X axis.

```
public class App extends JFrame implements Runnable{

    int x=0,y=250;

    public void run() {
      for(;;) {
        try {
          repaint();
          x++;
          Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch(Exception e){}
      }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) { 
      g.drawOval(x,y,30,30);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App frame= new App();
        frame.setTitle("Bounce");
        frame.setSize(400, 450);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(frame);
        t1.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: [Drawing a rectangle that won't disappear in next paint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683533/drawing-a-rectangle-that-wont-disappear-in-next-paint) Should go over what your problem is and how to fix it. You need to use `paintComponent(Graphics g)` and call `super.paintComponent(g)` to get rid of that "trail".

Comment: Ouch. This is very bad approach in general. Whole GUI runs outside of EDT.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to call `super.paint` in your `paint` method:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
  super.paint(g);
  g.drawOval(x,y,30,30);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a multi-threading issue, you just never "erase" the ovals you draw for the previous x. Your `paint` method needs to call `super.paint()` in order to clear the previous ovals. This is explained [here](http://www.edu4java.com/en/game/game2.html) with almost the same code as you but without your issue!

Comment: Thanks mate it really helped !