# Trouble With Color Changing In My Java Swing Paint Application

Tags: java, swing, paint, graphics2d

1. Should I still be practicing Java Swing?
2. I'm trying to add functionality to my Java Swing Paint Application by adding a choice to change brush colors. However, when I'm finished choosing a different color in the color chooser, all of the old marks change into that chosen color along with my new line marks. I wanted the old marks to stay the same color as before.

(Pictures below)

[Using black ink. Drawing something.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61GBw.png)

[Deciding to change the color to green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cz0Q4.png)

[Both the old AND new lines change to green.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBZfL.png)

This is not the entire application(**tell me if you need the rest**), but I believe the problem has something to do with incorrect table manipulation. The "shapeFill" table which matches colors to the lines("shapes" table) is not working correctly.

```
   public class TestPane extends JComponent{

    private List<List<Point>> points;
    private ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();

    public TestPane() {

        points = new ArrayList<>(100);

        MouseAdapter ma = new MouseAdapter() {

            private List<Point> currentPath;

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                currentPath = new ArrayList<>(100);
                currentPath.add(e.getPoint());

                points.add(currentPath);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                Point dragPoint = e.getPoint();
                currentPath.add(dragPoint);
                repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                currentPath = null;
            }

        };

        addMouseListener(ma);
        addMouseMotionListener(ma);
    }


    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        Iterator<Color> fillCounter = shapeFill.iterator();
        for(Shape s : shapes) { // I believe problem is somewhere around here?
            g2d.setPaint(fillCounter.next());
            g2d.setStroke(new java.awt.BasicStroke(10));
        }

        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        for (List<Point> path : points) {
            Point from = null;
            for (Point p : path) {
                if (from != null) {

                    Shape line = new Line2D.Float(from.x, from.y, p.x, p.y);
                    g2d.draw(line);
                    shapes.add(line);
                    shapeFill.add(lineColor);
                }
                from = p;
            }
        }
        g2d.dispose();
    }

}

public JButton createButton(String title) {
     JButton button = new JButton(title);
     button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if(e.getSource() == colorChooser) {
                    Color chooser = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "Select color", lineColor);
                    lineColor = chooser;
                    shapeFill.add(chooser);
                    repaint();
                }else if(e.getSource() == shapeFillArrayList) {
                    System.out.print("\n");
                    for(Color index : shapeFill) {

                        System.out.println(index);
                    }
                }
            }

     });

     return button;
}
```

Comment: Using a `BufferedImage` as the painting surface might be part way to an answer to this problem. Here is an [example of painting to a buffered image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12683632/418556). *"This is not the entire application(**tell me if you need the rest**),"* No, we don't want a code dump of your entire code. Having said that, the most attention you will get from me based on what you've posted is in this comment. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for the useful links. I appreciate it. I also solved my own question already.

Comment: Choices - you could also store the color of the `Point`s and/or `Shape`s, so that when `paintComponent` is called, you have all the state information you need to re-create the output

Comment: @MadProgrammer That's similar to what I did to fix my problem, although I reworked the entire program so much that it doesn't look like my original code anymore. Thanks for your help though! I am new here.

Comment: *"I also solved my own question"* Glad you got it sorted. :)