# code for simple sketching doesnot work well

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I am a newbie in java and also in java Graphics. I wrote a simple code for sketching but it is not working well. when i drag my mouse little quickly some pixels are missed. Here is my code..

```
package test;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class testdraw extends JPanel{
    public int x1;
    public int y1;
    public int x2;
    public int y2;
    public testdraw(){
    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
            x2=e.getX();
            y2=e.getY();
            repaint();
            x1=x2;
            y1=y2;

        }


    });

}
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g;
        g2.drawLine(this.x1, this.y1,this.x2,this.y2);;

    }
}
```

Main class..

```
package test;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class testdrawmain {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        testdraw td=new testdraw();
        frame.add(td);
        frame.setSize(350, 350);
        frame.setVisible(true);

   }

}
```

Could anybody please tell me what is wrong. Please suggest me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        x2=e.getX();
        y2=e.getY();
        repaint();
        x1=x2;
        y1=y2;
```

x1 and x2 will be the **same** after this regardless of where you call `repaint()` -- not very useful.

Instead do the assignment **before** getting the mouse position.

```
        x1=x2;
        y1=y2;
        x2=e.getX();
        y2=e.getY();
        repaint();
```

If you want to draw all points, then create an `ArrayList<Point>`, add to the list in the mouse motion listener and in paintComponent iterate through the list.

Also:

- `paintComponent` should be protected, not public.
- You **must** call the super's `paintComponent` method in your own override.
- Please have a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6105437/522444).

---

**Edit**
Your comment:

> My application can draw like paint...so when drag mouse every time start and end coordinate will change

Then you have two options: using a `ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>>` or drawing on a BufferedImage and displaying the BufferedImage within your paintComponent method.

Comment: My application can draw like paint...so when drag mouse every time start and end coordinate will change ....

Comment: @sovon: Then you have two options: using a `ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>>` or drawing on a BufferedImage