# ask error load drawline

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I want to make program load line from database.I've been setting at database every coordinat using `double` .but im getting error when i try to load from database and want to drawline in jpanel it's didn't appear in my jpanel.how to fix it? this is my code.

```
    ArrayList<Shape> linesList = new ArrayList<Shape>();
    shape line = null;

    public void loadline(){
        while (rs.next()) {
            double x1 = rs.getDouble("coorX");     //getting coordinate
            double y1 = rs.getDouble("coorY");
            double x2 = rs.getDouble("coorX2");
            double y2 = rs.getDouble("coorY2");
           line =new Line2D.Double(x1,y1,x2,y2);
           linesList.add(line);
        repaint();
        revalidate();
        }
    }catch(Exception E){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error load data");
}
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error sql");

    }}
```

and this is my paint component method

```
 protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setColor(birumuda);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    for(Shape content : linesList){
        g2d.draw(content);
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: you have to load value from JDBC to util.List, then to invoke paintComponent by JCOmponent.repaint, inside paintComponent to loop in vakues stored in  util.List

Comment: What is the meaning of `shape`?

Comment: i got error in drawing line.
@mKorbel
how to invoke paint component by jcomponent repaint?can you give me example what should i do to fix it?

Comment: i've been edit my script now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should throw a NullPointerException. Where do you initialize your g2d variable? Your graphics look to be done incorrectly. You should 1) read the data in within a background thread, and store it into a collection, probably an ArrayList. Once this is done, notify Swing on the event thread so that you can draw the data within a JPanel's paintComponent method. See the [painting tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more on Swing graphics.

Comment: can you give me example what should i do?

Comment: @FRIDY: something similar to my code in an answer to a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6105437/522444).

Comment: i've been edit my script now.like this.but why didn't appear now?

Comment: @FRIDY: hard to tell without runnable code. It could be that the linesList collection is empty when the component draws itself, it could be that the component is too small to show the lines. Your best bet at this time is to create and post a [mcve].